# Magento 1.9.3.1 integration with odoo erp

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi guys I was looking into integrating my magento 1.9.3.1 with Odoo erp 8. Would this be possible ? And if so how would I go about achieving such feat?

Answer (score 0):

**Odoo Bridge For Magento** : If you are looking for any magento odoo connector then this module is well suited for your requirement. Basically this module provides two way communication between Odoo (formerly known as Openerp) and Magento , ie. you can synchronize data from Magento to Odoo and Odoo to Magento

https://store.webkul.com/Magento-OpenERP-Bridge.html

Try this one too [Magento Connector for OpenERP](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-connector-for-openerp.html)

Comment: Shall check the tone out. Bottom one is for magento 1.7. Have you used these beforehand ?

Comment: I haven't used this one.. ...last one is Compatible to 1.9 as well..